Is “it takes two to tango” also used in purely positive contexts?
I have been looking at the origin and definition of “it takes two to tango”, and it seems that the expression is often used with a negative connotation, or at least in neutral contexts.

For example, several definitions I found highlight the use of this expression to indicate responsibility for a situation or argument. See below (emphasis mine).
Farlex Dictionary of Idioms:

Two parties involved in a certain action or situation, especially a wrong that has been committed, are usually both responsible in some way.

Collins Dictionary

…a situation or argument involves two people and they are both therefore responsible for it.

Cambridge Dictionary

said when you want to emphasize that both people involved in a difficult situation must accept the blame, or that an activity needs two people who are willing to take part for it to happen

Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:

used to say that if a problem involves two people, then both people are equally responsible


I would like to know if this expression is also used in very positive contexts. I imagine something like this:

– You’re amazing! You did it!
– It takes two to tango. I couldn’t have done it without you!

PS: If this doesn’t work, I am interested to know if there is a more appropriate idiom out there for such scenarios.

Your "positive" example sounds forced and an attempt at some sort of humour/light-heartedness. I don't think it works. You should assume that the idiom is always negative.

@Greybeard That's not my intention. though. I really want to know if the phrase is also used in a positive context like giving credit for an achievement.

That's not my intention. though. Yes I know, that's why I wrote sounds forced and an attempt at some sort of humour/light-heartedness. Your intention has been defeated  by the misuse. You should assume that the idiom is always negative.

@Greybeard Okay I see. I actually don’t mind it being perceived as humorous/light-hearted and at the same time as a compliment or positive statement. But I understand that it sounds forced to you and not humorous in a good way.

It can be, but it must be used in situations where it makes sense - ones that actually require two people cooperate, not just when trying to share something. That's what's missing from your example.

I think your example is fine.

it takes two to tango
The active cooperation of both parties is needed for some enterprises,
as in We'll never pass this bill unless both parties work out a
compromise—it takes two to tango. This expression dates from the
1920s, when the Latin American tango became a very popular dance. It
was popularized by the singer Pearl Bailey in her 1952 hit song of
that name written by Al Hoffman and Dick Manning.
The American
Heritage Dictionary of Idioms (On a Farlex page) (The song)


tango (n.)
figurative. Frequently in proverbial phrase it takes two to tango.
1952 There are lots of things you can do alone! But, takes two to
tango.
Hoffman & Manning, Takes Two to Tango (song) 2
[OED online]

Note also:

It takes two to tango is a common idiomatic expression which suggests
something in which more than one person or other entity are paired in
an inextricably-related and active manner, occasionally with negative
connotations
Wikipedia


Examples illustrating the positive, cooperative side of the expression:

It take two to tango. It takes many more for a book. let me first thank two colleagues for their never failing and enthusiastic help in
launching this book...
Helmuth Nyborg (ed.); The Scientific Study of
General Intelligence (2003)


It takes two to tango: Strong public-private collaboration is key for discovering an implementing effective productive development
policies to bring out the best in existing economic activities and to
foster economic transformation.
Blurb for Eduardo Fernández-Arias et
al.; Two to Tango: Public-Private Collaboration for Productive
Development Policies (2016)


It illustrates that we cannot perform without the interplay between
formal structures and relational mechanisms. It takes two to
tango. And it also takes several parties to deliver a successful
project, making interorganizational collaboration a key focus area for
many researches (Nezmi et al. 2022).
Marian Bosch-Rekveldt and Hans
Bakker; "Key Drivers for Collaboration in Construction" in Sina
Moradi et al. (eds.); Routledge Handbook of Collaboration in
Construction (2024)


It Takes Two to Tango
In order for a group to create something together, the various
participants all need the ability to lead and to surrender.
Heinz
Robert; Vibrant Collaboration (2021)


He reminded us once again that in the area of leadership, as in so
many other areas of human endeavor, it takes two to tango.
Richard Couto; Reflections on Leadership  (2007)


In a sense, the concept of It Takes Two to Tango is the essence
of successful marriages. A marriage is the joining of two people who
work together as a team, sharing everything, and always supporting each
other.
Charles Schmitz and ‎Elizabeth Schmitz; Building a Love that
Lasts (2011)

Gary Smalley and Norma Smalley; It Takes Two to Tango: More Than 250 Secrets to Communication, Romance and Intimacy in Marriage (1967)

Some of those examples seem to be contrasting "it takes two to tango" with something positive: "It take two to tango. It takes many more for a book.", "It takes two to tango. And it also takes several parties to deliver a successful project" There's also the possibility that the meaning has changed over time. I think it sounds very odd in the OP's example: even if it's not always negative, that doesn't mean it's obviously positive. But citations such as Wikipedia saying it's only occasionally negative are worth more to counter dictionaries saying it's usually negative.

@StuartF I don't think that's giving "two to tango" a negative sense, just saying that some things are even more positive. E.g. it takes two to do something good, it takes a village to do something great.

@StuartF It's unusual to come across a proverb or similar with no context at all. Even positive collaborations aren't all roses: toes may gets stepped on during a tango.  I agree the percentages of positive/negative contexts might have changed--I don't know.

I think this answer definitively affirms that "it takes two to tango" can appear "in purely positive contexts"—which is the core question that the poster asks. Well done, DjinTonic!

I mean. It can be, I guess, but I've never actually heard it used to mean anything except "I don't care who's right and who's wrong, you're fighting and I'm going to punish you both."
